# How would you incorporate probability into this graph theory problem?

Tags: probability, graph-theory

A non-closed path is chosen at random on the complete graph K9. All
paths are equally likely. What is the probability that the path contains
the edges {23} and {34} given that it is length 6? Given that it has
the edge {89}?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A (directed) path of length $6$ can be encoded as a string of $7$ digits from $\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$, where each digit represents a vertex from $K_9$. For example, one possible path could be:
$$
1254367
$$
But observe that since paths are undirected, we can reverse this path and it would still be the same thing. So the total number of paths of length $6$ in $K_9$ is:
$$
\frac{9!}{2 \cdot (9 - 7)!}
$$

---

Now suppose that we want to count the number of paths of length $6$ that also contain the edges $\{23\}$ and $\{34\}$. Then this amounts to finding the number of strings of $7$ digits from $\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$ that contain $234$ or $432$ as a substring, then dividing the result by $2$. To do this, notice that:

- There are $2$ possible substrings: $234$ or $432$.
- There are $5$ possible positions that this substring can be in the path:
  $$
  234???? ,~~~ ?234??? ,~~~ ??234?? ,~~~ ???234? ,~~~ ????234
  $$
- There are $9 - 3 = 6$ remaining vertices that can fill the $4$ remaining question marks.

Hence, the total number of paths of length $6$ in $K_9$ that also contain the edges $\{23\}$ and $\{34\}$ is:
$$
2 \cdot 5 \cdot \frac{6!}{2 \cdot (6 - 4)!}
$$